# How to run very long mysql queries - or alternative to the situation described

Tags: php, mysql, caching

The short version:

I am looking for a way to be able to run VERY-VERY long queries in MySQL: like 20-30k long queries.

***Is this possible?

If yes, what are the drawbacks? Will the queries be much slower because of this?***

The reason why I want to be able to do this is explained in the following section, bear with me, it's a rather long read:(

**EXPLANATION WHY I WANT TO DO THIS:**

I have several mysql tables which are connected to each other, and which are being queried by my code, to obtain different result sets.

For the purpose of this question, I will try to explain 3 of my tables: `Ads`, `AdsGeometry`, and `AdsAmenities`.

The first table, named `Ads`, is an `InnoDB` table, which contains information about an advert on my website. It has an auto-incrementing unique id, called `AdId`.

The second table, named `AdsGeometry` is a simple extension to the `Ad` table, which is a `MyISAM` table, because it contains a `geometry` mysql type, namely a Point, which holds the Latitude and Longitude location of the advert. Because of the indexes, this table had to be separated from the `Ad` table, because MySQL can't index `geometry` on an `InnoDB` table. (At least I couldn't index it, and everywhere where I checked, it said that indexes for `geometry` types only work on `MyISAM` table structures). This table is connected to the `Ads` table, via the `AdsGeometry.AdId` field.

The third table, named `AdsAmenities`, is also an 'InnoDB' table, and a relational table, which connects multiple adverts from the `Ad` table, with multiple amenity types from the `Amenities` table.

In my website, there will be two layers of filtering for all the different ads in the database. The first layer of filtering, consists of filtering by either `location`, `price`, `category`, etc. is done with the url, and the second layer of filtering, is an ajax based filtering, which is done without browser refresh, through ajax calls made to the server. The second layer of filtering consists of filtering by 'amenities', or 'points of interests' nearby the advert.

For the second layer of filtering, the number of ads after a new filter is applied, is showed instantly to the user.

So for example, a user asks to list all the adverts in UK, London. He clicks on the link **www.mysite.com/adverts/UK/london** which filters for every advert in the desired location, and on that link he will be presented with a further filtering option, which for example could state, that there are 500 adverts which have *pools*, 256 adverts which have *sea view*, etc. When a user clicks to filter for every property which has a pool, the script auto-updates the list, and also the filtering options, to adjust to the new numbers, because it is possible, that there were 256 adverts with *sea view*, but there are only 127 left, which have both *sea view*, and *pool*.

To make these searches faster, I am caching a lot of the information. For example, when the first layer of filtering is done, my script generates a query in the likeness of:

`SELECT Ads.AdId FROM Ads, AdsHierarchy WHERE AdsHierarchy.ads_AdId = Ads.AdId AND AdsHierarchy.locations_LocationId = 5363453`

This query fetches every AdId which is inside the location with the specified id(for example *London*).

The result of this query(a bunch of AdIds), and the results of basically almost every query which could be slow, are being cached in a local file, for 24 hours, so when another user wants to fetch every advert from London, we won't run an expensive query again, just use the AdIds that are stored.

The mysql queries for the second filter layer looks something like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT(amenities_AmenityId), COUNT(AdsAmenityId) as total FROM AdsAmenities WHERE AdsAmenities.ads_AdId IN (".$SQLbase.") GROUP BY AdsAmenities.amenities_AmenityId`

In the past, the `$SQLbase` variable was replaced with a list of AdIds separated by commas, but as this lead to very very long queries(long as in text-wise, not run-wise, imagine when there are 40000 AdIds returned from the first result set, and I list all of them in the query), and errors from MySQL, I've changed it, so it is replaced with the first MySQL query instead. In my experience this was only a tiny bit slower, then using the listed values, so I've decided to keep it this way.

So basicaly how my caching works is as follows:

> program checks first query, if not cached, runs it, and caches in a local file it's results
>   program checks second query, if not cached, runs it, and caches in a local file it's results

This way, the first user who visits the site, may experience a bit of slow-down, but for every other user who wants to get the exact same result set(same location for example), the results are returned very very fastly.

But as of today, I've introduced a new kind of search method, the users can now search also by drawing a polygon on an interactive map, and get the results of that polygon. The first filter query for a search like this looks something like this:

```
SELECT Ads.AdId FROM Ads
     , AdsGeometry 
 WHERE AdsGeometry.AdId = Ads.AdId 
   AND ST_CONTAINS(GeomFromText
                     ('Polygon
                       (
                         ( -4.7560501098633 37.025032151632
                         , -4.7512435913086 36.877972847795
                         , -4.5871353149414 36.873578654705
                         , -4.6022415161133 37.03489909082
                         , -4.7560501098633 37.025032151632
                         )
                        )
                       '), AdsGeometry.GeomPoint);
```

As it is very unlikely that two users will draw the exact same polygon, I've decided that I won't cache the results of these queries. But, if I will insert the first query, in the second queries `WHERE` clause, I can't cache the second query either, because of the same reason, which leaves me with two possibly slow queries. This is why I want to change back the second query, so instead of a query-in-query mode, it should use list-in-query mode.

Comment: a) innodb spatial indexes are possible in 5.7. b) You can set `max_allowed_packets` up to 1GB, which should be enough. c) I would suggest to rethink your caching strategy. Do not denormalize data into a cache and then reinterprete it. You can e.g. save the location in london into rows as a cache and then apply your polygon (and maybe other filters) to that subset you know is in london. And you might want to filter in javascript anyway (so not every little movement of the polygon has to result in a new query).

Comment: @Solarflare Could you elaborate on the c) point please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry never got to the end of your long description, in answer to your short question, Yes you can have a MySQL query of any length. However you must make sure that the MySQL global setting `max_allowed_packet` is bigger than your query length. In your case, the following should do it:

```
max_allowed_packet=30000
```

The number follows the normal MySQL convention for sizes. Here 30000 refers to bytes so I could have written it as:

```
max_allowed_packet=30K
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

You will hit the usual problems relating to parsing 30K of data but compared to the query time this is nothing to worry about.

Comment: is this set in bytes, or kilobytes, or?

Comment: A TL;DR answer to a voluminous question. Love it :)

Comment: Updated answer to include your additional question